# 11GHz,100 watts microstrip power divider

Tags: power, frequency

is it possible to build 100 watts, microstrip power divider work in 11GHz?

Answer (score 3):

No . the losses and tolerances are too high for etched tracks at this wavelength

Assuming you could achieve 1dB insertion loss that means over 10 Watts radiated in the strip.

Answer (score -1):

Copper foil of standard thickness (1 ounce/foot^2) has 70 degree Cent/watt of thermal resistance, if all the heat flows along the foil and none of the heat flows DOWN thru some dielectric and then into an underlying plane or heatsink.